# GooglePlaces API Swift 3 Issue

Tags: ios, swift

I seem to have picked up a few errors since updating to swift 3

```
        // Issue #1
        let correctedAddress:String! = self.searchResults![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.symbols)
        print(correctedAddress)
        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)&sensor=false")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
            data, response, error in

            do {
                if data != nil{
                    let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary

                    // Issue #2
                    let results = dic["results"] as! [String: Any]
                    let geometry = results["geometry"] as! [String: Any]
                    let location = geometry["location"] as! [String: Any]

                    let lat = location["lat"] as! Double
                    let lon = location["lng"] as! Double

                    self.delegate.locateWithLongitude(lon, andLatitude: lat)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

issue #1:
correctedAddress, as an example, returns value `"%51%75%C3%A9%62%65%63%2C%20%43%61%6E%61%64%61"`. Nevertheless, for some reason the url constant returns nil and causes a crash.

I don't understand why it returns nil. I can replace `correctedAddress` inside the url with the value `%51%75%C3%A9%62%65%63%2C%20%43%61%6E%61%64%61` so the full url is

`let url = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%51%75%C3%A9%62%65%63%2C%20%43%61%6E%61%64%61&sensor=false")` and it works fine.

issue #2:
It crashes just at `let results` to which i get back the error of `Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x108bb0c08) to 'NSDictionary' (0x108bb1108).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code for your Issue#2

```
let results = dic["results"] as! NSArray
for result in results {
    let strObj = result as! NSDictionary
    let geometry = strObj["geometry"] as! NSDictionary
    let location = geometry["location"] as! NSDictionary
    let lat = location["lat"] as! NSNumber
    let lon = location["lng"] as! NSNumber
}
```

For issue#1, try the below code

```
let valueAtIndex = self.searchResults![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.symbols)
guard let correctedAddress = valueAtIndex else { return }
let adrString:String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(correctedAddress)&sensor=false"
let url:URL = URL(string: adrString)!
```

Comment: Issue #2 is solved but issue #1 isnt. Could you explain why how it solves issue #2 and why my code doesn't work?

Comment: Actually, the issue is not with your code but rather the server returning the response.

Also in Swift 3 while evaluating a variable to a value using `\()` for concatenation or any other purpose, you don't apply exclamation mark at the end i.e. `!` then it would try to create a url with something like this :
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Optional("%51%75%C3%A9%62%65%63%2C%20%43%61%6E%61%64%61")!&sensor=false"` which returns Url as nil, so that is the reason for issue1, so looking at this, try to debug the issue1 code, there'll be a very small issue in there.

Comment: And pertaining to issue2

The issue is that the response from the server is all messed up so i had to play around a lot and figure out which type to cast the response as.

Although an interesting question, so i opened playground and started playing with the response type and wallah..

It got resolved fortunately :)

Cheers!!

Comment: Yeah I noticed that with the `Optional` in the middle of the address. I tried tried your code too and still have `Optional` in the string and can't seem to unwrap it

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the logs, where you are getting optional.

Comment: Edited your answer as i managed to find it. Should make sense when you see it. adrString would return `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Optional(\"%57%56%2C%20%55%6E%69%74%65%64%20%53%74%61%74%65%73\")&sensor=false"`